# regex how can I split this word?

Tags: regex

I have a list of *several* phrases in the following format

```
thisIsAnExampleSentance
hereIsAnotherExampleWithMoreWordsInIt
```

and I'm trying to end up with

```
This Is An Example Sentance
Here Is Another Example With More Words In It
```

Each phrase has the white space *condensed* and the first letter is forced to *lowercase*.

Can I use `regex` to add a space before each `A-Z` and have the first letter of the phrase be *capitalized*?

I thought of doing something like

```
([a-z]+)([A-Z])([a-z]+)([A-Z])([a-z]+) // etc
$1 $2$3 $4$5 // etc
```

but on *50 records* of *varying length*, my idea is a poor solution. Is there a way to `regex` in a way that will be more *dynamic*? ***Thanks***

Comment: It may be easier to Iterate over the strings and just add spaces before each capital letter.

Comment: something like ([a-z]+)+(([A-Z])([a-z]+))* ? Does that work?

Comment: ...but srsly what language or tool are you using - it can make quite a bit of a difference

Comment: For "hiIWantAPuppy", I assume you want to get "Hi I Want A Puppy"?  Is it ok if "hiSQLAndXML" gets tranformed to "Hi S Q L And X M L"?

Comment: @xanatos @CodeJockey I'm using the regex too in the `Sublime Text 2` code editor.
@EdwardLoper Yes.

Answer (score 2):

A Java fragment I use looks like this (now revised):

```
result = source.replaceAll("(?<=^|[a-z])([A-Z])|([A-Z])(?=[a-z])", " $1$2");
result = result.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + result.substring(1);
```

This, by the way, converts the string `givenProductUPCSymbol` into `Given Product UPC Symbol` - make sure this is fine with the way you use this type of thing

Finally, a single line version could be:

```
result = source.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + source(1).replaceAll("(?<=^|[a-z])([A-Z])|([A-Z])(?=[a-z])", " $1$2");
```

Also, in an Example similar to one given in the question comments, the string `hiMyNameIsBobAndIWantAPuppy` will be changed to `Hi My Name Is Bob And I Want A Puppy`

Answer (score 1):

For the space problem it's easy if your language supports zero-width-look-behind

```
var result = Regex.Replace(@"thisIsAnExampleSentanceHereIsAnotherExampleWithMoreWordsInIt", "(?<=[a-z])([A-Z])", " $1");
```

or even if it doesn't support them

```
var result2 = Regex.Replace(@"thisIsAnExampleSentanceHereIsAnotherExampleWithMoreWordsInIt", "([a-z])([A-Z])", "$1 $2");
```

I'm using C#, but the regexes should be usable in any language that support the replace using the `$1`...`$n` .

But for the lower-to-upper case you can't do it directly in Regex. You can get the first character through a regex like: `^[a-z]` but you can't convet it.

For example in C# you could do

```
var result4 = Regex.Replace(result, "^([a-z])", m =>
{
    return m.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
});
```

using a match evaluator to change the input string.

You could then even fuse the two together

```
var result4 = Regex.Replace(@"thisIsAnExampleSentanceHereIsAnotherExampleWithMoreWordsInIt", "^([a-z])|([a-z])([A-Z])", m =>
{
    if (m.Groups[1].Success)
    {
        return m.ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
    }
    else
    {
        return m.Groups[2].ToString() + " " + m.Groups[3].ToString();
    }
});
```

Comment: well, you could do it all with a single perl regex (using the `\U` convention in your replacement expression - see @Qtax's answer, but that very well may not apply, since we don't know what language or tool is being used

Answer (score 1):

A Perl example with unicode character support:

```
s/\p{Lu}/ $&/g;
s/^./\U$&/;
```